# Python string to list for editing

Tags: python, text-processing

I'm trying to do some text processing that's mostly re.sub() commands. I know I can't alter a string, but even after I try converting the string to a list and changing it element by element, there's still no change in the output.

What I want to know is: a) where I'm going wrong with my code and b) would I be better off using a bytearray than a list?

```
with open("responses_test.txt", "r+") as f:
  responsesIPA = f.readlines()

for row in responsesIPA:
  row = list(row)
  row = [i.lower() for i in row]
  row = [re.sub("3", u"\u0259", i) for i in row]
  row = "".join(row)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable , but you can assign a new value , ie `row = re.sub("3", u"\u0259", row)`

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: *there's still no change in the output*: did you mean to save `row` somewhere after you changed it?

Comment: @t.m.adam that would not be the problem in that case. Plus, the code you provided expects `row` as string, when it is a list.

Comment: @Uriel what i mean is that the OP can replece his for loop with this : `for row in responsesIPA: row = re.sub("3", u"\u0259", row)`

Comment: To clarify, an example of the input is a line of text like:

F EJ D3R

The output I'm hoping for from that is:

f ej dər

Comment: @bkula in that case `for row in responsesIPA: print(row.lower().replace("3","\u0259"))` would suffice.

Comment: A little help on MCVE, make the question actually demonstrate the problem. Instead of reading a file, just comment that out and say responsesIPA = [u'J FE D3R'] and actually print something in the code snippet.  Then tell us what you actually printed and what you expected to be printed.

Comment: Thanks, @KennyOstrom! Very solid advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert to list to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

```
for row in responsesIPA:
   row = row.lower()
   row = row.replace("3","\u0259")
   print row
```

Comment: I tried this, as well as doing

    row = re.sub("3", u"\u0259", row)

instead of 

    row = row.replace("3","\u0259")

but my output is still exactly the same as my input.

Comment: @bkula what is your python version?

Comment: How exactly are you using row? Are you trying to reflect your updated string to responsesIPA list?

Comment: Not that it really matters here, but I wouldn't modify the loop variable.  Just print the function results, and leave "row" under the control of the for loop.

Comment: 2.7. This solution is actually working for me now. I discovered that the issue is I had a print statement outside the for loop. Like I was printing responsesIPA because eventually there will be a lot more replace statements in there. Not sure why having the print statement outside the loop is causing this not to work, though.

Comment: Not sure why would you try to print a loop variable outside of loop. If you can update question with code where you are printing it, we can help.